# Simple public-key authentication on Windows without SSH

Tags: windows, windows-authentication

I'm trying to automate a process using a batch file which requires authentication on a remote machine:

```
net use "\\remoteserver" -/u:username password
```

However, I don't want to store `password` as plain-text in the batch file.

I know that in SSH setups, we do passwordless logins by inserting a public key in the host's authorized_keys file. However, SSH is not an option on the machines I'm working on.

Does Windows have a similar authentication scheme?

Comment: The short answer is yes, you do this by setting up a domain so that the server trusts the client.  Then you do not require a password for the `net use` command.

Comment: Thanks. If I might ask another rookie question, can machine belong to two domains? Our machines are already part of a domain administered by IT, and I don't have access to the domain settings there. I only have access to the server and the client machines.

Comment: Sorry, you have already exceeded my knowledge of Windows administration. `:-)`